# How to get the number of objects in an array that match the required parameters in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have array like

```
messages: [{
                message: "message",
                from: someId,
                createdAt: Date.now(),
                read: false
              },
{
                message: "message",
                from: someId,
                createdAt: Date.now(),
                read: false
              },
...
]
```

How can I get number of this objects that match the parameter **read === false**

Comment: Is your collection going to be read more from or written too more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your message is an array, you can do it with aggregation framework :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      unread: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$messages",
            as: "message",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$message.read",
                false
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/64S1i_g98RA)

Comment: what if i need just count w/o list of messages?

Comment: replace $addFiels by $project

Comment: thanks. one last question i have. how can i use two or more parameters in query? like read === false and from === 1? i was trying use $match but it doesn't works

Comment: cond: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$message.read",
                    false
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$message.from",
                    1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }